# Has there ever been a comic series that takes place on starhaven for the whole run?

Tags: dc, comics

Starhaven seems like it would be an interesting place to do a full run. I don't know much except that it is dawnstar's and wildstar's home. I looked up starhaven on dc wikia and wikipedia but they dont mention if there are comics taking place on the planet. It seems legion of super heroes and R.E.B.E.L.S have some volumes.

Answer (score 0):

It's very hard to provide solid evidence of a negative.

That said, to the best of my recollection, I'm not aware of any series that has solely taken place on Starhaven. And, while I think there have been a few stories besides the L.E.G.I.O.N. story where Vril Dox finds her and gives her powers that have taken place on Starhaven, the only other one I have some vague recollection of would only have been 1-2 issues long (I think there was a Dawnstar-focused story that included someone from home, if not a trip there, in the mid-80s in *Tales of the Legion of Super-Heroes* before that started reprinting year-old stories from *Legion of Super-Heroes* vol. 3 (vol 1 was a 70's reprint book, vol. 2 took over numbering from *Superboy*/*Superboy and the Legion of Super-Heroes*)).

Note: I haven't read all of the New 52 Legion stories, or the "threeboot" version.